# How to press a key on function call to move to its body

Tags: vim

Can you give me plugin or something like that for vim to move the cursor or open a source file that contains the function's body when pressing a key on its prototype or call

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for the [tags](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Browsing_programs_with_tags) feature.

Comment: i think no, just i want to press a key when my cursor is on a function call to move the cursor to the function body (if you use visual studio it's like the Go To Definition feature)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just use a simple solution without plugins (despite being less intuitive and case-specific), you can use /searchstring to search for the keyword.

Example: `/myFunction` would search for and go to the first instance of that function (the prototype, if you are at the top of the file) and pressing `n` would send you to the next time it is used (which might be the begninning of the body, but it also might be some time when it is called in a different function).

It's not a plugin or anything, but it's useful nonetheless.

Comment: Another quick way to search is to press `*` to search for the next occurrence of the word under the cursor. (`#` searches for the word backwards.)

Comment: Guys i know that, it's not the subject :(

Comment: Just a "quicker-in-the-present-but-not-as-good-as-the-other-answer-if-you-take-the-time-to-understand-tags" kind of solution. Happens all the time.